# How to prevent drop down list item from repeating in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using vb.net, I have something like this :

```
If textbox1.Text = "abc" Then
    ddl1.Items.Add(1)
    ddl1.Items.Add(2)
    ddl1.Items.Remove(3)
    ddl1.Items.remove(4)
End If

If textbox1.Text = "efg" Then
    ddl1.Items.Add(3)
    ddl1.Items.Add(4)
    ddl.Items.Remove(1)
    ddl.Items.Remove(2)
End If
```

How I'm going to make when I key-in "abc" more than one time its only add once in drop down list menu and not repeated. same goes when I insert "efg" ?

If I need to handle inside the dropdownlist_SelectedIndexChange how I'm going to do it ?

Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the drop down list before you figure out what to add into it, like this:

```
ddl1.Items.Clear()

If textbox1.Text = "abc" Then
    ddl1.Items.Add(1)
    ddl1.Items.Add(2)
End If

If textbox1.Text = "efg" Then
    ddl1.Items.Add(3)
    ddl1.Items.Add(4)
End If
```

This simplifies your logic to only care about adding the items you want to show to drop down list, instead of having to worry about removing other items.

Answer (score 1):

Before you are adding an item in the drop down, first check if it is already added. If not, only then go ahead and add it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`FindByText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbytext.aspx) method to see if the item already exists in the list before adding it.